# Python Scrapy check xpath url image exists

Tags: python, url, xpath, scrapy

It is possible to check the url of the image extracted with xpath?

The idea is to check the url if it's broken or not, if is not, extract the image url, else show a referential image.

I have this code:

```
    for ntp in response.css('div.content-1col-nobox'):
        for imgurl in ntp.xpath('//div/p[3]/img/@src'):
            if imgurl != 404:
                picUrl = response.urljoin(ntp.xpath('//div/p[3]/img/@src').extract_first())
            else:
                picUrl = ("https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/ZIMAAOSwImRYLZw9/s-l1600.jpg")

        writer.writerow({
        'PicURL': picUrl\})
```

Any help will be appreciate it

Comment: You can try to `import requests` and check as `if requests.get(imgurl).status_code != 404`

Comment: I get this error: `raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for '<Selector xpath='//div/p[3]/img' data='<img style="max-width:620px;text-align:c'>`

Comment: That's because `@src` doesn't look like an absolute URL (e.g. "http ://somesite.com/images/image.jpg"). Can you extract correct `@src`?

Comment: the absolute url is extracted in picUrl: `response.urljoin(ntp.xpath('//div/p[3]/img/@src').extract_first())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andersson was right, the problem is in the absolute URL.

This is what I did:

```
for ntp in response.css('div.content-1col-nobox'):
    imgUrl = response.urljoin(ntp.xpath('//div/p[3]/img/@src').extract_first()) 
    if requests.get(imgUrl).status_code != 404:
        picUrl = response.urljoin(ntp.xpath('//div/p[3]/img/@src').extract_first())
    else:
        picUrl = ("https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/ZIMAAOSwImRYLZw9/s-l1600.jpg")
    writer.writerow({'PicURL': picUrl\})
```

**EDIT** @Andersson Thank you for the correction

Comment: `if`/`else` block indentation seem to be incorrect. Should it be on the same indentation level as `imgUrl` definition?